# "type mismatch" error while using :+ method on a List

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have just started learning scala. I was trying to write a function to reverse a List of any arbitrary type.

Below is the code:

```
def reverse [A] (l:List[A]):List[A] = {
     val size:Int = lenList(l) // i have implemented this func separately
     if (l.isEmpty) List()
     else {
              var newList = List()
              for (i <- 1 to size)
              {
                  var temp = l(size - i)
                  newList = newList :+ temp //type mismatch error here
              }
     newList
    }
   }'
```

This is the error when the above code was compiled:

[image: Error]

When I changed the `newList` declaration to `var newList = List[A]()` (which is the same type as the List passed as parameter) the code compiled successfully.

My question is:

1. Why is there a type mismatch on the line `newList = newList :+ temp` when `newList` is of type `List[Nothing]` and `temp` is an element of `type A`?
2. Why does the compiler say, `Found:List[A]` when there is no `List[A]` type involved in the statement?
3. Could anybody tell me the reason why this particular type mismatch error occurred?
4. Also I want to know the reason of why the code compiled when I changed the declaration?
5. What effect my declaration had on the statement which was initially throwing the error?

I believe below error message would have been justified in this situation

```
found:List[Nothing] 
Required:List[A]
```

rather than what I encountered:

```
found:List[A]
Required:List[Nothing]
```

As `newList` of type `List[Nothing]` was used in the statement and the element I tried to append was of `type A` then it is understandable that required type should be `List[A]`.

Comment: Calling `List()` corresponds to the factory `List.apply[T]`, where `T` is inferred as `Nothing` as you doesn't specify it, neither on the `val` declaration by indicated the explicit type or on the factory call. either `val newList: List[A] = List()` or `val newList = List.empty[A]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
var newList = List()
```

The type of the `newList` is `List[Nothing]`. And if you are new to scala, `Nothing` is a subtype of every other type. Practically it is kind of useless, when we have to write any data to it. We will see why so.

When you do `newList :+ temp`, you are appending temp (of type `A`) to a `List[Nothing]`. So for the compiler, the type inference predicts that this new list must be of type `List[A]`. (Think of it as, if you creating a list of lions, birds and snakes, wont you call this new list as a list of animals?)

So the generated list is of type `List[A]`. And then you try assigning it to itself (`newList =`). Which originally is a `List[Nothing]`. In scala, with `var`, you can change the value but not the type. And here we are trying to change the type of `newList` from `List[Nothing]` to `List[A]`.

Hence the error and its explanation

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Now i understood that `found:List[A]` referred to the resulting type of the value returned by expresion 'newList :+ temp' which was a mismatch for required type `List[Nothing]` of newList.

Answer (score 0):

use `newList.+:(temp)` to append to list